# What are the common features of pro-union and anti-union laws?

Tags: legislation, civil-rights, employment, labor-union

I often hear people talk about pro-union and anti-union laws being formulated in legislatures, but I don't really understand their differences.

What sort of provisions usually appear in these laws? Specifically, I want to know how these provisions achieve their desired outcome from a strategic standpoint.

Some case studies from different countries would be nice too.

Comment: Wikipedia has a lot of articles on labor law, trade unions, and employment law, e.g. [Labour law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Labour_law), [Union busting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_busting), [Right-to-work law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-to-work_law), [United Kingdom labour law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Kingdom_labour_law). Have you looked at them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Off the top of my head, here are several:

- (pro) Union representatives on the board.  [Germany](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codetermination_in_Germany).  Special roles for trade unions in government negotiations, even when a trade union *isn't* represented in a given company. France, [Partenaires Sociaux](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partenaires_sociaux) (see Gilles' comment).
- (pro) Need to belong to the union in order to hold covered jobs for a unionized company.  A (barely) weaker version of this is when you don't need to be in the union but still have to pay dues.  [Cases in Canada](https://albertaviews.ca/union-membership-optional/) (yes, that looks like a very anti-union biased website).  To be fair, benefiting from union-negotiated benefits while not paying dues is a good case study for [free rider](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free-rider_problem) problem.
- (pro) Unions are brought in via a simple, easy to put on ballot, majority vote, but can't be easily turfed out by the same if a majority of workers do not feel they serve their interest.  Or a decertification vote has higher barriers to even being put on the table.  [Canada](https://knowledge.leglobal.org/canada-recent-changes-to-the-canada-labour-code-include-the-removal-of-mandatory-certification-votes-and-the-implementation-of-a-higher-threshold-required-to-trigger-a-decertification-vote/)
- (anti) Unions are in all companies, but it is the same, State-directed union (or unions).  The workers' interests are now "protected" by body which has a conflict of interest as the state also owns the companies. USSR, [China](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All-China_Federation_of_Trade_Unions).
- (anti) Some countries [prohibit unions](https://www.ethicaltrade.org/blog/top-10-worst-countries-workers-rights).
- (pro)  [Legal prohibitions](https://nbmediacoop.org/2020/02/17/where-there-are-scabs-there-is-violence-why-quebec-and-bc-banned-strikebreakers) on hiring replacement workers during a strike.
- (anti) Limited right to strike for [essential workers](https://www.ilo.org/legacy/english/dialogue/ifpdial/llg/noframes/ch5.htm#6).

See also [right to work laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-to-work_law)

Comment: Mandatory unionization has been illegal in Europe since 2006. http://hudoc.echr.coe.int/fre?i=003-1553007-1625438

Comment: Haha, yes, I saw that on the Alberta anti-union website.  Question:  are you talking about mandatory membership for each worker, #1?  Or is it, #2, the fact that each company *has* to have a union?  Not the same thing.  Errr.... could you edit whatever you think is a relevant example of when it *did* apply pre-2006, but *only if this change concerned* #2?  #1, mandatory membership is alive and well in various Canadian provinces.

Comment: Upon reading your link, that is #1, mandatory membership for each worker.  Still happens in Canada, and covered by my third bullet point.  There is also the #2 variant, for example, "past 50 workers a company needs to be union-certified".

Comment: I'll add it as an anti

Comment: Membership in a trade union is not and has never been mandatory in France. ([Loi du 21 mars 1884 relative à la création des syndicats professionnels « Waldeck-Rousseau »](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k5844227m/f4.item.texteImage) — while that law doesn't state explicitly that an employer could make union membership mandatory, article 7 explicitly states that one may withdraw at any time, and the only penalty can be that the current year's union dues remain due, not losing your job.) What do you mean by “mandatory unionization” as opposed to mandatory membership?

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' a rule that companies have to put in place a union, past a certain size or upon meeting certain criteria, *without* needing vote by workers themselves.   i.e. something like:  past 500 employees, all companies need to have a trade union set up, automatically.  I'll remove the France bit.

Comment: Companies don't “put in place” a union: they have to allow whatever unions the workers want. There are various things that scale with company size, such having a workers' council where union representatives (*délégué syndical*) may participate as such in addition to representatives of the workers (*membre du comité social et économique*, formerly *délégué du personnel*). Unions can also get involved in company-level agreements if they're representative in the trade branch or region, even if they're not represented inside the company. Is this the sort of thing you're refering to?

Answer (score 15):

Anti-union laws generally make it harder for:

- Unions to form, by allowing employers to [discriminate against unionised workers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/At-will_employment), or requiring onerous processes to be followed for the formation of a recognised union, or not requiring employers to recognise and negotiate with a union even when it represents the majority of workers.
- Unions to operate, by not requiring employers to provide space and time for union organisers, or requiring onerous conditions for strike ballots.
- Industrial action to be effective, for instance by allowing striking workers to be fired and/or other labour to be bought in, or by banning or limiting the actions of union pickets.

Pro-union legislation makes unions easier to form, strikes and other industrial actions easier to call, and limits what employers can do in response. It also imposes collective bargaining requirements on employers (i.e. that they must recognise a union and negotiate with it as representatives of the workers).

Answer (score 4):

I will just give the partial answer for [denmark](/questions/tagged/denmark), and thus mostly pro-union laws.

1. Trade union fees are tax exempt.
2. Unions are given the administration of some unemployment benefits, meaning they can use that to build a big organisation. (this is a little more complex)
3. There is no minimum wage. (note 1)
4. There is a special court for union disputes with managers.
5. There are rules that enforce different kinds of collective representation.
6. Worker-elected representatives are harder to fire.
7. The right to strike is in the law.

And then the one rule that is anti-union.

1. Managers have the right to lead workers. (note 2)

Here is a good wiki reference about the general idea for Denmark:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexicurity

*Note 1*: The minimum wage seen from a Scandinavian perspective is the last resort to implement when trade unions loose power. E.g. in Germany the minimum wage was not introduced until 2015 and it was the biggest trade union Ver.di that accepted it had to be implemented because trade unions had lost a lot of power.

The general problem for the trade union is that e.g. if a café is blocked that pay minimum wage then that is per definition legal, where-as when there is no minimum wage then workers will more often get a trade union specific salary. E.g. Taxi drivers can negotiate a salary for Taxi drivers etc.

*Note 2*: To understand the September Compromise that forms Denmark then it is important to know that in 1899 there was a strike where all workers in the cities were on strike, and farmers where driving food to the cities to support the workers. Inspired by communism the workers wanted a society where leaders did not manage, but the Agreement established that managers could lead the workers.

Comment: minimun wage are nothing with being anti or pro union. Union can be in favor or againts it. it does not impact their existence or efficiency

Comment: I wouldn't say that "Managers have the right to lead workers" is directly union-unfriendly but together with "4 the court for arbitration between unions (and their members) and the employer and 7. the right to strike" is giving a clear message to employer : NO strike busting ie direct replacement of employees with strike breakers, so negotiate and deal with the union.  Together with the main contracts with the unions ie duty of peace it removes a lot of reasons for conflict.

Comment: Why would you say managers have the right to lead workers is anti union? Isn't it the job of managers to lead workers?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "workers should siege production"? If you are using that as why it is anti union it should be explained in your answer. Also please explain why a minimum wage is destructive? From everything I have seen in the past that is the opposite of what is happening. In the US a lot of union jobs are over double what the minimum wage is.

Comment: @ThomasKoelle and in france all union are in favor of the minimun wage but it does not matter anti and pro law are law that made union more/less difficult to exist or that impact their fonctionnement not law that their are in favor or against

Comment: Tried to include the comments in my answer as 2 notes. Read this answer as 100% from the point of denmark, especially regarding minimum wage.

Comment: I would 100% disagree with a minimum wage being bad as there should be no reason why worker have to form a union in order to get paid a living wage. Businesses should be required to pay a living wage at a minimum and workers should not be forced into a union in order to get one. Unions should be for making sure that employees are treated well in general and are getting the correct wage which is likely well above a living wage. Also would ask if managers are not leading workers who is?

Comment: 1) Ok, I will just leave a link about minimum wage. https://euobserver.com/opinion/150145 notice that the authors are the absolute top of Trade Union Confederations in the Scandinavian countries. 2) Regarding leading then the workers back then wanted democratic company structures instead of the capitalists owning the factories, e.g. people should not profit from other peoples work.

Comment: So you are saying workers should be screwed over if they can't get a proper union to fight for them? The point of a minimum wage is to prevent workers from getting screwed over by forcing a company to to the right thing. There are many work places that are small enough that there will never be a union. Trying to count on a union to keep wages fair is a way to screw over workers. That is exactly like people in the US who get tipped wages fighting to keep the tipped wage even though it screws over a lot of people who don't get a fair amount of tips.

Comment: I am an activist in Denmark, we block restaurants and other business and help employees get better salaries. I am aware that this may seem odd in e.g. an American context where workers can work hard and by themselves get higher salaries, but this is what works in Scandinavia.

Comment: @JoeW I think the argument is, in Denmark, a minimum wage would lead to *lowering* some wages because it would become legal to pay the minimum. Possibly not an argument that would occur to someone used to America.

Comment: @user_1818839 That doesn't make any sense to me at all, why would setting a minimum wage prevent employees from forming a union and demanding higher wages? All I see it doing is preventing people from getting underpaid. In the end you should not need to protest/block a business in order to get them to pay a fair wage.

Comment: I am thinking you have a big misunderstanding of how things work in America if you think working hard will get yourself a higher salary. There is much evidence that it is not the case and hard workers don't get a higher pay and plenty of examples of promised raises not given.

Comment: Yep, maybe make a US specific answer, that would be cool. I know a lot about US companies in Denmark though and after the main blockades of e.g. McDonalds in the 80s then they also now see the advantages of collective bargaining.

Comment: I am also confused. Perhaps there is a situation in which the existence of a minimum wage could actually drive down wages, if it convinced employees that there was no need for a union. Is this the reasoning of unions for opposing minimum-wage laws in Scandinavia? It seems unclear from the answer.

Comment: @Obie, yes (minimum wage can drive down wages), and no, per note 1, the need for a minimum wage arises when the unions *have already lost* power.